# Problem pulling data from GetIt to stream builder

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, stream-builder, flutter-change-notifier-provider

Error text:

> Null check operator used on a null value The relevant error-causing
> widget was StreamBuilder<List>

```
ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => getIt<ModelCreator>(),
          child: StreamBuilder(
              stream: getIt<ModelCreator>().chatList(),
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<ChatModel>> snapshot) {
                var _data = snapshot.data!; <- The error is here
                return Container();
              }),
        ),
```

*There is no problem with empty Container, that part is full.*

> Thats getChatList() func

```
  Stream<List<ChatModel>> getChatList() {
var data = _firebase
    .collection('Users')
    .doc(_fireauth.currentUser!.uid)
    .collection('Chat List')
    .orderBy('Last Message Date', descending: true);

return data.snapshots().map(
    (event) => event.docs.map((e) => ChatModel.fromSnapshot(e)).toList());
```

}

> Thats it ChatModel

```
  factory ChatModel.fromSnapshot(
  QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> doc) {
return ChatModel(
  id: doc.id,
  image: doc['Image'],
  phone: doc['Phone'],
  photo: doc['Photo'],
  username: doc['Username'],
  createdDate: doc['Created Date'],
  displayMessage: doc['Display Message'],
  lastMessageDate: doc['Last Message Date'],
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

the snapshot data can be null. So before accessing the `snapshot.data` you should check

```
if(snapshot.hasData)
```

if it returns true, you can access the data without any issues

Comment: I did it before but the problem is that the data is not coming.

Comment: have you checked if the api is returning data?

Comment: I update the question, can you check it again?